# How to load MagentaJS musicVAE model into Python magenta MusicVAE

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, magenta

I am attempting to load the MusicVAE model from the [Drumbot Project](https://github.com/magenta/drumbot) into a python MusicVAE model.

However, the constructors for each are not the same.  The Javascript version accepts a URL to a folder([link here](https://storage.googleapis.com/magentadata/js/checkpoints/groovae/tap2drum_2bar)) which contains 3 files: a weights_manifest.json, a shard of data, and a config.json file.

The python implementation takes 2 mandatory arguments: a config object, and a checkpoint directory containing checkpoint files.

These two seem to be incompatible, and I'm not sure how I would go about converting the JS checkpoint directory into something usable with the Python model.  I've looked into the tfjs_converter utility, but it does not accept the format that the JS version is in as an input.